# Need help in Linq, I need to add the data to a List

Tags: xml, linq, windows-phone-7

This is the structure of my XML file.

```
<Resto>
<ID>2</ID>
<Name>name</Name>
<Category>categroty</Category>
<Places>
  <Address>
    <Location>loc</Location>
    <Number>num</Number>
    <Longitude>"empty"</Longitude>
    <Latitude>"empty"</Latitude>
  </Address>
</Places>
</Resto>
```

The longitude and Latitude are empty, I'm not using them now, these are for later updates.
And some might have more than 1 Address:

```
<Address>
 <Location>loc</Location>
    <Number>num</Number>
    <Longitude>"empty"</Longitude>
    <Latitude>"empty"</Latitude>
  </Address>
```

Also i did this query which is working perfectly fine:

```
var anything = from resto in appDataXml.Descendants("Resto")

                     select new limit()
                     {
                         ID = resto.Element("ID").Value,
                         Name = resto.Element("Name").Value,
                         Categories = resto.Element("Category").Value
                     };
```

I have these in the limit class:

```
    public string Name{get;set;}
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string Categories{get;set;}
    public List<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
```

and "Address" is another class with Location and Number get/set.

Anyway my question is how can i query the Xml file and add the Location and Number to the Addresses List so that i can add these values to a ListBox.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

To play with the XML data if you are using .net version 3.5 its better to user [**LINQ to XML**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx).

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24376/LINQ-to-XML

**or**

[Manipulate XML data with XPath and XmlDocument (C#)](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9494/Manipulate-XML-data-with-XPath-and-XmlDocument-C)

Answer (score 0):

```
var doc = XDocument.Load("test.xml");
List<Address> locations = (from address in doc.Root.Element("Places").Elements("Address")
         select new Address
         {
              Location = address.Element("Location").Value,
              Number = address.Element("Number").Value,
         }).ToList();
```

Make sure you have a root node (like `<parent>`):

```
<parent>
  <ID>1</ID>
  <Name></Name>
  <Category></Category>
  <Places>
    <Address>
      <Location></Location>
      <Number></Number>
    </Address>
    <Address>
      <Location></Location>
      <Number></Number>
    </Address>
  </Places>
</parent>
```

**Update:**
If your xml looks like this:

```
<Restos>
  <Resto>
    <ID>1</ID>
    <Name>name</Name>
    <Category>categroty</Category>
    <Places>
      <Address>
        <Location>loc1</Location>
        <Number>num1</Number>
        <Longitude>"empty"</Longitude>
        <Latitude>"empty"</Latitude>
      </Address>
    </Places>
  </Resto>
  <Resto>
    <ID>2</ID>
    <Name>name</Name>
    <Category>categroty</Category>
    <Places>
      <Address>
        <Location>loc2</Location>
        <Number>num2</Number>
        <Longitude>"empty"</Longitude>
        <Latitude>"empty"</Latitude>
      </Address>
    </Places>
  </Resto>
</Restos>
```

You can use this code to parse it:

```
var doc = XElement.Load("test2.xml");
List<Resto> restos = (from resto in doc.Elements("Resto")
                        select new Resto
                        {
                            ID = resto.Element("ID").Value,
                            Name = resto.Element("Name").Value,
                            Category = resto.Element("Category").Value,
                            Addresses = (from address in resto.Element("Places").Elements("Address")
                                        select new Address
                                        {
                                            Location = address.Element("Location").Value,
                                            Number = address.Element("Number").Value,
                                        }).ToList()
                        }).ToList();
```

Where `Resto` and `Address` are defined as:

```
public class Resto
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }
    public List<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
}

public class Address
{
    public string Location { get; set; }
    public string Number { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I did as you said, but i got a nullReferenceException. Any idea ?

Comment: @user1200204 Are you applying this code to a different (maybe larger) xml file? Can you update your question with a more complete xml structure?